# i would like to manipulate the "AS age" column from table1

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

below is a query i wrote

```
SELECT *, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(age) AS age FROM table1
```

and i would like to manipulate the "age" column from the query above

for instance like:

```
SELECT  * FROM table1 WHERE age BETWEEN 1 AND 9
```

how can i do it from this query

```
SELECT *, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(age) AS age FROM table1
```

my results will be to return rows that contain the range of the age

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `query` as a `subquery` like

```
SELECT t2.* FROM
( SELECT t1.*, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(age) AS age FROM table1 t1 ) t2
WHERE t2.age BETWEEN 1 and 9
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides an extension to the `HAVING` clause that allows you to do what you want:

```
SELECT *, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(date) AS age
FROM table1
HAVING age BETWEEN 1 AND 9;
```

Note:  I assume that you have some sort of *date* column that you want the year of.  Taking the year of something called `age` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: the query managed to return the row between that age range,now i want to count those rows and i manipulated that query as:
SELECT COUNT( YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(purchaseDate)) AS age FROM productsmarket HAVING age BETWEEN 1 AND 9 

its returning nothing,how can i make it work?